# I can't solve an error "Universes are unbound"

Tags: coq

I'm developing a library for googology in Coq. I ran into a problem.

```
Set Universe Polymorphism.
Set Polymorphic Inductive Cumulativity.

Inductive Sum@{i j} (A : Type@{i}) (B : Type@{j}) : Type@{max(i,j)}
  := left : A -> Sum A B | right : B -> Sum A B.

Definition Foo@{i j k l} (A : Type@{i}) (B : Type@{j}) (C : Type@{k}) : Type@{l}
  := Sum@{i _} A (Sum@{j k} B C).
```

I expected `_` to be filled with `max(j,k)`. However, I got an error:

```
Universes {***} are unbounded.
```

Is there a way to express these constraints well?

Comment: Code on Github is not acceptable, and neither is *See the line 282-323*. All relevant code must be here, in the post itself, so that it remains available to future users of this site. Please provide it here in your question in the form of a [mcve]. If you can't do so, then your question isn't appropriate for this site. See the [help] for more information.

Comment: I could not organize my thoughts. Added one that minimized the problem.

Comment: I thought that example was enough. I have improved.

Comment: I correct that: "I have improved" -> "I will have improved"

Comment: @Hexirp Note that the `max` universes cannot be used in general contexts; only in the universe level of inductive types. That is why `Sum` is accepted, but `Foo` isn't when you put the `max` annotation.

Comment: Thank @ArthurAzevedoDeAmorim!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel it makes sense to add `ij` that satisfies `i <= ij` and `j <= ij`. I should have thought more.